# Let $a,b$ be real numbers with $|a|<1$. If $2ab+b^2 >3$ then prove that $8a^3-6a+b^3>0$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Let $a,b$ be real numbers with $|a|<1$. If $2ab+b^2 >3$ then prove that  $8a^3-6a+b^3>0$.

According to me it is false. For $a=0$ ,$ b^2>3$ so $b^3>0$ is false. Am I right?

Comment: Did you check whether it says "Let $a,b$ be positive real numbers" ?

Comment: If b can be negative it's false

Comment: Also we need more information as to whether this is for all real numbers or just "there exists" a,b.

Answer (score 0):

It's not false, assuming $ b $ has to be positive.

For $a = 0:$

If $b^2 > 3$ then $|b| > \sqrt{3}$

And $b > \sqrt{3}^3 > 0$

If b can be negative:

Then you must state that $(-b)^3 < 0$, thus why it would be false.